# LWC- How to get the <td> input value in datatable

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

How to get the **price** and **quantity** entered by the user
and store them in **selectedLines**?
The final result I want to get is:

[{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WlZpAAK","Name":"ROI-000030","ProductName__c":"Product Data 270820",**"Price__c":"1500""Quantity__c":" 60"**},
{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WcuCAAS","Name":"ROI-000008","ProductName__c":"Product Data 260820",**"Price__c":"1800","ProductName__c":" 57"**}]

HTML

```
<template>
    <h3 class="slds-section__title">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:orders" alternative-text="Order Item" title="Order Item" size="small"></lightning-icon>
        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Selected order details">&nbsp;&nbsp;Selected order details</span>
        
    </h3>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Order Code">Order Code</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Produc tName">Produc tName</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Price">Price</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Quantity">Quantity</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody for:each={selectedLines} for:item="item" key={item.Id}>
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                <th scope="row">
                    <div >{item.Name}</div>
                </th>
                <td >
                    <div >{item.ProductName__c}</div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div ><input class="slds-input" value={item.Price__c}></div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div ><input class="slds-input" value={item.Quantity__c}></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <lightning-button label="Submit" variant="brand" onclick={submitData}> </lightning-button>
    </div>
       
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedLines = [{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WlZpAAK","Name":"ROI-000030","ProductName__c":"Product Data 270820"},
{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WcuCAAS","Name":"ROI-000008","ProductName__c":"Product Data 260820"}];
    submitData(){
        //How 
        console.log('submit success = ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedLines));
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire onchange and use lightning input so whenever you change value of input you will assign it like this

```
    <template>
    <h3 class="slds-section__title">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:orders" alternative-text="Order Item" title="Order Item" size="small"></lightning-icon>
        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Selected order details">&nbsp;&nbsp;Selected order details</span>
        
    </h3>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Order Code">Order Code</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Produc tName">Produc tName</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Price">Price</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" scope="col">
                    <div title="Quantity">Quantity</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody for:each={selectedLines} for:item="item" key={item.Id} for:index="index">
            <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                <th scope="row">
                    <div >{item.Name}</div>
                </th>
                <td >
                    <div >{item.ProductName__c}</div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div >
                        <lightning-input type="number" data-id={index} value={item.Price__c} onchange={handlefirstchange} name="input1" variant="label-hidden" label="Enter a number" ></lightning-input>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td >
                    <div ><lightning-input type="number" data-id={index} value={item.Quantity__c} onchange={handlesecondchange} name="input2" variant="label-hidden" label="Enter a number" ></lightning-input></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
        <lightning-button label="Submit" variant="brand" onclick={submitData}> </lightning-button>
    </div>
       
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedLines = [{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WlZpAAK","Name":"ROI-000030","ProductName__c":"Product Data 270820"},
{"Order__c":"8011s0000000mrtAAA","Id":"a0e1s000000WcuCAAS","Name":"ROI-000008","ProductName__c":"Product Data 260820"}];
    submitData(){
        //How 
        console.log('submit success = ' + JSON.stringify(this.selectedLines));
    }
    handlefirstchange(evt){
    
        this.selectedLines[evt.target.dataset.id].Price__c=evt.detail.value;
        

    }
    handlesecondchange(evt){
 this.selectedLines[evt.target.dataset.id].Quantity__c=evt.detail.value;
    }
}
```